# Is there a way to enter raw data into PostgreSQL to duplicate a row except certain columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I have a raw file csv with personal information including addresses: there are two columns each for an address, and two distinct addresses (four fields in total).

So I might have `Fred, Flinstone, ID#12345678, 123 Street, Apt 6, Seattle, WA, 87319, 567 5th Ave, Seattle, WA, 87321` in my CSV along with several other columns that I need.

My question is, is there a way to import or set up a `CREATE TABLE` statement that will take this data and split it into two rows:

`0: Fred, Flinstone ID#12345678, 123 Street, APT 6, Seattle, WA, 87319`

`1: Fred, Flinstone ID#12345678, 567 5th Ave, Seattle, WA, 87312`

I know that there's `Array_arg` for splitting an array into distinct rows, but I don't know about populating a new table from it. Basically my problem right now is that we set up this database with only the primary/first listed address, and now that is causing significant issues when trying to join this table. I **do not want** to set up two tables where I can join to get both addresses. I just want to know if there's a way to do this on an import, as my searching hasn't turned up what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this:

- Use a foreign data wrapper
- Use copy and staging table.

You can define a foreign table that can access the csv table as if it were a sql table with a foreign data wrapper. You can then use insert as select to insert the records in the target table. You would need to run the insert as select twice: first for the primary address and then for the secondary address.

Instead of using the foreign data wrapper approach you can first load the table into a staging table with the copy command. And then use the staging table to run insert as select into the target table.